# How to convert BSON to JSON String using mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Python dataframe is persisted in mongodb collection in BSON format. How to convert BSON to JSON String? Tried with below query but is failing with "Unsupported conversion from binData to strin". Appreciate any help on this.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ 
  { "$project":
    {
      "data":"$data",
      "value": {"$convert": { "input": "$data", to: "string" } }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi, is correct that MongoDB store data in BSON format, but you do not need to "convert" it to JSON. Just query you data and you will get a JSON format.

Comment: I have pandas dataframe inserted into mongodb and the same is inserted as BSON. I want to write a mongo query to get JSON output of dataframe.

Comment: Could you add a sample document to the question?